# Manipulating geometry of layer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geometry, editing

I went through different Stack Overflow questions, tutorials and the official PyQGIS cookbook. Somehow I cannot make a basic manipulation of the geometry of a layer's features.

This is the code I try to run. All that happens is that the layer is loaded into the project totally unchanged and the `print(new)` gives me the old coordinate values (but the `print(geometry())` inside the loop gives me the correct new geometry). Is it because it is a `.kmz` file?

```
import os 
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer
)

layer = QgsVectorLayer("/my_layer.kmz", "myLayer", "ogr")
layer.startEditing()

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    id = f.id()
    geom = f.geometry()
    geom.translate(10,10)
    f.setGeometry(geom)
    layer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({ id : geom })
    print(f.geometry())

layer.commitChanges()

#Check if new geometry was written into layer
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    new = f.geometry()
    print(new)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

I am using QGIS 3.16

Comment: Did you try the same code using a `"/my_layer.shp"` instead of `"/my_layer.kmz"` after saving kmz to shp to confirm the issue is with the kmz format not elsewhere?

Comment: You may have to export your layer as a shapefile or geopackage so that it will allow you to edit it.   I have not edited a kmz in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is not working because of your input data format.

I've tested your code is working with shapefile and GPKG but it does not work with KML and KMZ files.